# Is redux-form worth using in an apollo-react-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, redux-form, apollo

I understand that redux-form handles reducers and actions for me which is a plus. But as far as I can tell the data will be returned as JSON upon submission and the added complexity to my app may not be worth while.
The redux-form workflow seems to be counter intuitive to the apollo graphQL wrapper that takes a mutation function prop and a gql tag in the react work-flow.
Is redux-form the wrong tool for the job or is there some insight I am missing?
I would like to hear about any alternative tools others are using in react-apollo.
-Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I stand corrected.
Redux-form is worth using in Apollo-React-Redux.

After some research I found a minimumly invasive way to implement redux-form into an Apollo-React app if anyone is interested:

https://github.com/jferrettiboke/react-auth-app-example/blob/master/client/src/containers/SignInFormContainer.js

It took 2 lines in my index.js to include the formReducer (as expected) and sampling his signin form and its container.

His containerized method actually matched up well with the usual react- apollo work flow.

Thanks

Comment: That's awesome, I'm glad you figured it out! If you have time, it would be awesome to add a recipe to our docs about it, on the http://dev.apollodata.com/react/ website in a new page under "recipes".

Comment: Given that Apollo v2 doesn't use Redux, do you think it would still be possible to use Redux-form in a minimally invasive way?